# How to make this 'if sentences' sequentially?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
function FadeAnimation(){
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    let delay= 8000;
    var numtemp_index = 0;
    if(num % 4 == 0){1
     var starCountRef = fade_sliderref('#eclipse_1');
      db, '1/'+ fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_one'temp_index);
        num++;

        setTimeout(()=>{
            if(num % 4 == 1){
                fade_slideronValue('#eclipse_2');
               starCountRef, fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_two'snapshot);
                num++;

                setTimeout(()=>{
                    if(num % 4 == 2){
                     var data = fade_slidersnapshot.val('#eclipse_3');
                        fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_three'});
                        num++;

                        setTimeout(()=>{
                            if(num % 4 == 3){
                                fade_sliderset('#eclipse_4');
                                fade_sliderref('#main_photo_animation_four');
                                num++;
                            }
                     db, '1/' + }temp_index);
                    }
                }, delay);
            }{
       "0": }data[0], delay);
   "1": }data[1]++,
   "2": FadeAnimation();data[2]
})};

function fade_slider(a){
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(a).fadeIn(4000);
        $(a).fadeOut(4000);
    })
}
```

I want to orperate this if sentences in order, but it doesn't work. Four photos are fading in and fading out simultaneouslyget the data from realtime database, and I wantthen update newly to make it orderlydatabase. HowSo, my goal is to fix this problem?connect onValue syntax and set syntax in one sentence. I guess setInervalinfer that await or setTimeout mightthen syntax will be the solutionsneeded, but I don't know how to do it. Please Help!

Comment: You have edited the question to a different question instead of asking a new question, you should not do this as even if your question is solved, that question can be useful to other community members. I am unable to edit your question, so you must undo the edit to your question. And, for asking this question, you can ask a new question.

Comment: @Ayush I don't know why this question is edited, and I think I made a mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the if statements are working sequentially but the thing is that it is so fast it seems to be fading simultaneously.

To solve that, in the if statement, you can add the `setTimeout()` function, and provide the if statement inside the function

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    // your next if statement goes here
}, 1000);
```

Here, a timeOut of 1 sec is given (1000ms).

We do this as `setTimeout()` is a callback function and if you only give the empty timeout inside the if statement, it will move forward in code.

The nesting of your if statements will look like this:-

```
let delay=1000; // setting value for timeout in ms
if(num % 4 == 0){
    fade_slider('#eclipse_1');
    fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_one');
    num++;

    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(num % 4 == 1){
            fade_slider('#eclipse_2');
            fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_two');
            num++;

            setTimeout(()=>{
                if(num % 4 == 2){
                    fade_slider('#eclipse_3');
                    fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_three');
                    num++;

                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        if(num % 4 == 3){
                            fade_slider('#eclipse_4');
                            fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_four');
                            num++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Another way to do this can make this a bit simpler to look:-

```
let delay=1000;
setTimeout(()=>{
    if(num % 4 == 0){
        fade_slider('#eclipse_1');
        fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_one');
        num++;
    }
}, delay);

setTimeout(()=>{
    if(num % 4 == 1){
        fade_slider('#eclipse_2');
        fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_two');
        num++;
    }
}, delay*2);

setTimeout(()=>{
    if(num % 4 == 2){
        fade_slider('#eclipse_3');
        fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_three');
        num++;
    }
}, delay*3);   

setTimeout(()=>{
   if(num % 4 == 3){
        fade_slider('#eclipse_4');
        fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_four');
        num++;
    }
}, delay*4);
```

It is the same thing but we are not nesting the code blocks and setting delay in the timeout to be more each time

///////EDIT///////
You could change the id of animations like `#main_photo_animation_4` instead of `#main_photo_animation_four` and use the simpler code:-

```
let i;
let num_pictures=4;
let delay=1000;

for(i=1;i<=num_pictures;i++){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(num % num_pictures == i){
            fade_slider('#eclipse_'+i);
            fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_'+i);
            num++;
        }
    }, delay*i);
}
```

This will now work for any number of images

Comment: I change the code, but it still doesn't work. Photos appear gradually(one photo->two photos->three photos->four photos), and eventually four photos are fading in and fading out. How can I fix it? I update the code in this post.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, you should not update the code in the question according to the answer as others would have problem seeing the answer.

Comment: @Default If the photos are fading and appearing gradually then, what's the issue you re facing?

Comment: Oh, I'm a beginner of stack overflow, so I didn't know that, Thanks! And I want to show a picture one by one, but the number of pictures increases as time flows. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Default check the edited answer where the code is simple ans short inside a `for loop` and also, it will work for any no. of images

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Promise`, `async/await`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    FadeAnimation();
})

async function FadeAnimation() {
    await fade_slider('#eclipse_1');
    await fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_one');
    await fade_slider('#eclipse_2');
    await fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_two');
    await fade_slider('#eclipse_3');
    await fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_three');
    await fade_slider('#eclipse_4');
    await fade_slider('#main_photo_animation_four');
}

function fade_slider(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $(a).fadeIn(4000, () => {
          $(a).fadeOut(4000, () => {
              resolve();
          });
      });
  })
}
```

Use jquery's `promise()`:

```js
function fade_slider(a) {
  return $(a).fadeIn(4000).fadeOut(4000).promise();
}
```